# NET Core jquery fires two times on textbox input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, partial-views

In my ASP Core 2.2. MVC project I have a header/filter div with a dropdown list and a search text box.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9 form-inline">
    <select id="ddlSelect" asp-items="Model.Ddl" class="form-control filter"></select>
    <input type="text" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search" id="tbSearch" class="form-control filter ml-2" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-right"></div>
</div>
```

using jquery I then do a partial reload of a list I have as a partial view:

```
<div class="section-list">
  @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialList1", Model);}
</div>
```

The jQuery code that listens for a change in select list or input in the textbox is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').on("change", ".filter", function() {
    showList(this);
    return false;
  });

  $('.content').on("input", ".filter", function () {
    showList(this);
    return false;
  });
});
```

`showList(this)` then makes a an AJAX request using `$('.section-list').load(url);`

The code works, but the problem is that when I input something into the `#tbSearch` textbox this is properly captured in the jQuery `input` listener and my partial view reloads. However after the initial partial reload the `change` event is fired and the partial view reloads again.

The result is correct, but I do not want the jQuery to fire twice. Is there a solution?

Comment: It's probably because the `input` event fires first, then the textbox loses focus and the `change` event fires. I'd suggest deleting the `change` event handler and just using `input` alone

Comment: Also note that the `return false` is redundant and can be removed

Comment: I need the `change`event to capture, if a user changes the selection of the dropdown (ddlSelect)

Comment: In that case restrict the selector for `change` to `select.filter`. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `input` event fires first on the textbox, then as the content is changed it loses focus and the `change` event is immediately fired.

To fix this you need to only use the `input` event on the textbox, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').on("change", "select.filter", function() {
    showList(this);
  }).on("input", "input.filter", function() {
    showList(this);
  });
});
```

Note that in both cases `return false` is not needed.